# WordPress custom navigation with sub-pages

Tags: wordpress

I can't figure out how to create a custom navigation for WordPress.

I would like to use pages as my navigation and sub-pages as drop-downs and fly-outs.

Example:

- Home
- tab-1

  - sub-page-1
- tab-2

  - sub-page-1
  - sub-page-2
  - sub-page-3
- tab-3
- tab-4

  - sub-page-1
  - sub-page-2

    - sub-sub-page-1
    - sub-sub-page-2
  - sub-page-3
- tab-5

It doesn't need to be styled like this but something like [Stu's example](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html). I need it to be dynamic because hard coding is not the way of the Coding Samurai!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-level navigation plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multi-level-navigation-plugin/

http://pixopoint.com/multi-level-navigation/

Comment: works great but overrides my stylesheet. Now on to the CSS part ;)

Comment: Yea, sorting out the CSS is important. Might depend on how well the CSS in the theme you're using is commented or designed.